# Is it possible to use DxUpload (in DevExpress Blazor) without having an API?

Tags: blazor, devexpress, blazor-server-side

I'm using `DevExpress` components in my `Blazor Server App` project. I want to use `DxUpload` component to upload an excel file to the server and do some bulk insert operations on the database. The [Documentation](https://docs.devexpress.com/Blazor/DevExpress.Blazor.DxUpload) says that I need to create a `WEB API` project. Do I have to use a separate `WEB API` while my project is `Blazor Server App`?

Answer (score 2):

I think this solution is really more of a hack then how DevExpress intends you to use their component. However, you can capture the file upload via the exposed **SelectedFilesChanged** event and then process the files yourself manually.

```
<DxUpload UploadMode=UploadMode.OnButtonClick
          SelectedFilesChanged="@SelectedFilesChanged"
          AllowMultiFileUpload="true" 
          @ref="MyUpload" >
</DxUpload>

<DxButton Text="Upload the First File" Click=OnButtonClick />

@code {
    private string FileServerPath => "\\\\server-02\\DATA\\";
    bool UploadVisible { get; set; } = false;
    IEnumerable<UploadFileInfo> Files { get; set; }
    UploadFileInfo FirstFile { get; set; }
    DxUpload MyUpload { get; set; }

    protected void SelectedFilesChanged(IEnumerable<UploadFileInfo> files) {
        Files = files;
        UploadVisible = files.ToList().Count > 0;

        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    protected async Task OnButtonClick(){
         selectedFile= Files.First();
         Stream stream = selectedFile.OpenReadStream(maxAllowedSize: 50000000);
         FileStream fs = File.Create(FileServerPath + selectedFile.Name));
         await stream.CopyToAsync(fs);
         stream.Close();
         fs.Close();
    }
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

Obviously the **OnButtonClick** method needs to be refactored for nullability, using statements, selecting the appropriate file in the collection ect. but this should point you in the right direction.